# Understanding variables from speech recognition paper in HMM-GMM

Tags: speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models, gmm

I am reading [this](https://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/%7Emjfg/mjfg_NOW.pdf) paper by Mark Gales and Steve Young on speech recognition using HMM-GMM. In page 205, second paragraph, it is written:

"*For each utterance Y<sup>(r)</sup> , r = 1, . . . , R, of length T<sup>(r)</sup> the sequence of baseforms, the HMMs that correspond to the word-sequence in the utterance, is found and the corresponding composite HMM constructed*"

I did not clearly understand what is Y<sup>(r)</sup> and Tsup>(r) ? Can someone clarify it ? I did not understand what does **r** and **R** stands for ?

Similarly in [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eianlane/publications/2012_Buthpitiya_Inpar.pdf) paper titled as : **A Parallel Implementation of Viterbi Training for Acoustic Models using Graphics Processing Units,** in section 2.1 the author mentions that :

"*Given a set of training observations Osup>(r) , 1 ≤ r ≤ R and an HMM state sequence 1 < j < N the observations sequence is aligned to the state sequence via Viterbi alignment.*"

I know both sentences are similar but in above paper as well I did not understand what is **r** and **R**.

Answer (score 0):

In HMMs, you have time-sequential observations. Speech recognition is a special task since the observation length is not fixed but variable.

As far as I understand an observation Y(r) is given as:

Y(r) = {Y_0, Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_R}
so that r is an index with r = 0, 1, ..., R.

**In this case, r is the count of observations and R is the last observation.**